# Как скачать много файлов через filezilla?

Tags: ftp

Привет. Надо скачать сайт Opencart, через filezilla. Интернет хороший. Но тем не менее файлов очень много примерно 18 000. Качает очень долго. Можно как то через FTP сделать архив либо скачать более быстро все эти файлы?

Comment: надо сделать архив. Но через FTP не получится. Надо заходит через SSH или панельку аля cPanel и там делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не обойтись для этой задачи только доступом по FTP, нужен доступ к командной строке (SSH для выделенных серверов или какую-нибудь веб-панель).

В консоли запаковать свой сайт:

```
tar -cvzf site_backup.tar.gz /home/clientid/websitefolder
```

После чего скачивать архив через FTP. Действительно, один крупный файл скачается *намного* быстрее, чем 18 000 мелких файлов.